# Are there any Programmable ROMs, that don't need specialist hardware to program

Tags: eeprom

I have an idea for a digital circuit. It needs a ROM, one that I can use on bread board. I have no programming hardware (I have RS232 serial, I²C, I may at a stretch be able to get hold of an Arduino with JTAG).

After programming it should act as a ROM, with

- parallel address (or reset and count: an internal counter that can be reset and clocked),
- separate parallel data

---

What I have found:

- Parallel EEPROMs thanks to @davetweed They are like non-volatile RAM, but with slow write, and limited write cycles. An example is [AT28C64B](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/AT28C64B-15PU/AT28C64B-15PU-ND/1008529?utm_adgroup=&mkwid=sWE2OFv7U&pcrid=337625225693&pkw=&pmt=&pdv=c&productid=1008529&slid=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9Iq94PqH5AIVGp7VCh11FQUtEAQYASABEgIgTPD_BwE)
- A similar question, about hybrid serial programmable, parallel read (may not exist). [Parallel EEPROM write to with I2C](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/381141/37672)

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: (you'll find I²C memory easily enough using the usual distributor websites' categories/search engines, but what you describe sounds like something you wouldn't solve using ROM chips in 2019. Really, describe the problem you want to solve with this.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks, I will search. I am out of touch with what is available. I am wanting to store some audio on it. I will then use a counter and a DAC to play it. Counter →ROM →DAC→opamp, or Counter →ROM →Delta Sigma →One bit amp (current amp) →capacitor →speaker.

Comment: @MarcusMüller put the answer part of you comment into an answer.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor that is not a goal you would accomplish with a parallel ROM.  You'd use an SPI flash (or at larger sized maybe an SD card) and a small MCU, or better yet a fixed-function decoder for a compressed audio format.

Comment: Note that you can program an AT28 by hand. Ben Eater has a couple videos about those, programming by hand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BA12Z7gQ4P0 and with a self-made Arduino programmer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K88pgWhEb1M

Answer (score 4):

The search term you're looking for is "**parallel EEPROM**" — for example, these offerings from [Microchip](https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/memory/parallel-eeprom). There are many other vendors with similar products (I have a box full of [Am29F010](http://noel.feld.cvut.cz/hw/amd/16736f1.pdf) that I'm saving for a rainy day), but specific recommendations are off-topic here.

Yes, you'll need a programmer, but since the interface signals are all logic-compatible, you can easily put one together using an Arduino and an appropriate socket.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check with your electronics disti as well. Many have services for programming. Its not free but may be an option if you are not wanting to buy a programmer. Note: I just grabbed a part for example purposes only.
[image]